# Index and match in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have two sheets, I want to retrive data from the first sheet according to 3 conditions: Month in row1, conditions in row 2, and operations from column B. Each shown in the table: each location have the same two operations.
[image: The data]

In sheet 2, I want to select the month from the list (Data validation, the months are linked from the table) then the data of that month only will be shown. I used the following code:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B1:K6,MATCH((B1= Sheet1!C1:K1)*(E2=Sheet1!C2:K2),0),MATCH(B3,Sheet1!B1:B6,0))
```

As seen in the picture: 
[image: Retrive data]

But I get an error that the data is not found even though I am sure it's there. Please guide me what did I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I used another code (This is C3):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C3:K3,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!C1:K1,0),MATCH(C2,Sheet1!C2:K2,0))
```

It worked, I only change te data range in each cell and the option (H, W, M with month). The weird thing is that it only works for January!!
[image: January]

But when I select Feb or March I get:
[image: Feb]

I feel confused what is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: While the merged cell on Sheet1 can be worked around the merged cells in Sheet2 cannot easily be worked around.  The value of a merged cell is stored in the upper left cell of the merged cell.  Which means A4 on Sheet is null and trying to link that to Sheet1 will fail.  Remove the merged cell on Sheet2 and put the value in all the cells.

Comment: That stil did not work. I updatedt my post above.

Comment: you haven't unmerge the cell as per advised by scott..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$K,ROW(),MATCH($D$1,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)+COLUMN()-3)
```

---

How it works:

```
MATCH($D$1,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)
```

finds the column of the selected month in Sheet1

```
+COLUMN()-3
```

offsets from that column to get `H`, `W` or `M` column

```
ROW()
```

gives same rows in `Sheet1` and destination sheet

```
INDEX(...)
```

returns the result

Comment: May I ask, in the range of MATCH(), $1:$1 takes all columns that have data?

Comment: Yes, ` $1:$1` references the entire row 1

Comment: nice answer.. really like it's matching criteria simplicity. ( :

Answer (score 0):

Do in Sheet2 C3 :

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$3:$F$4,MATCH(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A3,IF(Sheet2!$A3="",-1,0),0),Sheet1!$A$3:$A$8,0)-1,MATCH(Sheet2!$B$1,Sheet1!$C$1:$N$1,0)-1),MATCH(Sheet2!$B3,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$4,0),MATCH(C$2,Sheet1!$C$2:$E$2,0))
```

Idea : use offset to 'determine' the area for OP,CR & H,W,M search. put an If+offset condition to 'shift' the sheet2,columnA reference if it is blank.

Please share if it works/not. ( :

Comment: It give me "FALSE"..
I also used another code but I have no idea why it works only for Jan moth. I will add the update on the post.

Comment: it works for the created [sample file](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/EanGk01-dw5HkHo9tfYrueUBKZ72WIPM9kZrq8p-Ql6Q9A?e=JpndBa).. try to have a check should the sample file had wrongly recreated your case..